# MySQL datatable optimization for ratings like IMDB?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have got a lot of articles in a datatable, and I would like to create a rating system.
The portal is listing the articles very often with the average rating. Is it a good idea to store the average rating values to a temporary field after each votes? I mean:

```
USER table
ID: auto inc INT
NAME: varchar (50)

ARTICLE table
ID: auto inc INT
NAME: varchar (50)
OPTIMIZED_RATING: decimal (4,2)

RATINGS table
ID: auto inc INT
USER_ID: INT
ARTICLE_ID: INT
RATING: TINYINT
```

After the user votes, the engine is running a query, it counts the average value, and it updates the OPTIMIZED_RATING field of the article.
Or is there a better solution for it?
Thanks!

Comment: Well this question is primarily opinion-based.. MySQL can calculate average(s) pretty fast when you index correctly even when you have millions off records.. Besides normally normalisation would leave out calculated data to be stored as column.

Comment: Depends on how often votes come in.

Comment: Stack Overflow itself does store the vote result of down and upvotes but the question is how many records you have.

Comment: There are in this time 1000 records, but it will grow. If there is 200 votes for each articles, the RATINGS datatable size is 200,000 records.
I am listing 20 articles in a page, so the MySQL have to scan 20 * 200,000 records in a page load.
But when I update the optimized fields only, if a user votes, then it will be much less work for the MySQL.